Error 403 Forbidden on localhost when accessing custom directory on Debian 12
I've installed PHP, Apache2, MariaDB, and PHPMyAdmin.
Accessing localhost shows the "It works!" page. localhost/phpmyadmin also shows the phpmyadmin login page.
I've added the directory that I wanted to use in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Alias /pwl /home/user1/pwl
<Directory /home/user1/pwl>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

When I try to access localhost/pwl, it shows
403 Forbidden, You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.61 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80.
What should I do?

Does the Apache system user in fact have permissions to access that directory? What's the output of namei -l /home/user1/pwl and of getenforce? Do you have any relevant messages in dmesg?

namei -l output:
drwxrwsrwx www-data kay pwl

(kay being the username).
and yes, it's forbidden because www-data is not the owner of the directory. so i changed it with chown.

The 403 Forbidden error is due to the user "www-data" not having access/not being owner of the directory. I changed it with:
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/user1/pwl 
and at first glance, it worked. Localhost opened the sample index.html file.
However, the user (kay) now cannot access the pwl. I tried adding kay to the www-data group, like:
sudo chown -R kay:www-data /home/user1/pwl
sudo usermod -a -G www-data kay

and vice versa, but I still can't access the folder w dolphin and the localhost link both.
I found this blog abt linux file permissions (https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions) and ran chmod ugo+rwx /home/user1/pwl to give rwx perms to everyone. Now I can access the folder as user and through the localhost link.
I don't know if this is the best answer, but this worked for me.
EDIT:
after all that, I ran the commands mentioned by symcbean,
chmod -R g+rwx /home/user1/pwl 
chmod -R go-w /home/user1/pwl 
, And all is well now.

"chmod ugo+rwx" is (almost) never the right way to fix a permissions issue. Setting the group to www-data should have worked unless you forgot to run chmod -R g+rwx /home/user1/pwl or the user www-data is NOT in the www-data group. (And you really don't want directories directly accessible by the webserver to be writeable by the webserver).

yes, i did forgot to run that, my bad. should i just run it now?

For neatness, I'd suggest so - but really you want to make sure those files are read-only for the webserver uid unless strictly necessary (chmod -R go-w /home/user1/pwl)
